# Highcharts Network Graph link labels not shown consistently

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've been struggling for the past few days with Highcharts Network Graph Link Labels:

[network graph with link label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDhdC.png)

As shown in the screenshot, all labels are not displayed. We should see also 'test 2' between point C and point A.

The issue comes from the javascript arrow function. Whenever I remove it all labels are ok.

Currently, when the graph initializes all labels are here but fade away once it's done.

all details are [in JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Luminae/gv71w6af/7/)

`Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
type: 'networkgraph',
marginTop: 80,
backgroundColor: '#343a40' //couleur de fonds

```
},
title: {
    text: 'Network graph',
    style: {
        color: 'white',
    }
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'A Force-Directed Network Graph',
    style: {
        color: 'white',
    }
},
plotOptions: {
    networkgraph: {
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'clabel'],
        layoutAlgorithm: {
            enableSimulation: true,
            integration: 'verlet',  //euler or verlet euler takes into account velocity
            maxIterations:250,
            linkLength: 250
        },
        point: {
            events: { }
        },
        colors: [],
    },
},

series: [{
    id: 'language-tree',
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        shadow: false,
        bold: false,
        color: 'white',
        style: {textOutline: 'none'},
        allowedOverlap: false, style: {textOutline: false},
        linkFormat:'{point.clabel}', // \u2192 {point.toNode.name}
        y: -16
    },

    // Options for the links
    link: {
        color: 'white', // #9cd4d4 couleur des fleches 89CFF1
        width: 1,
    },

    marker: {
            enabled: true,
            radius: 12
    },

    nodes: [
    {'id': 'A'},
    {'id': 'B'},
    {'id': 'C'},
    ],

    data: [
    ['A', 'B', 'test 1'],
    ['A', 'C', 'test 2'],
    ],

}]
```

});
`
Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

I've tried to modify the highcharts main script before realizing issue was from the arrow function which I don't know how to enhance it.
I'd like to get all the labels shown in the middle of the each link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
.highcharts-label.highcharts-data-label {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I've tried to integrate that one in the JSFiddle but unfortunately could not make it work. Do you know where I should set that one?

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmsd2gqe/) - it's the one originally linked in your question, I just added this CSS rule.